# Failed install of Hyper V uses up 18GB of HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hyper-v, storage, disk-space

I've decided to try out the 'Hyper-V Windows 10 dev environment' on my laptop. Beginning this I only had about 20gb remaining so had to remove an additional 20gb from my hard drive, leaving me with 40gb free.(which is the recommended free amount to use Hyper-V)

I initiated Hyper-V Windows 10 dev environment through Hyper V quick create, but just before it finished installing the application stopped saying there wasn't enough free storage to complete the task.

Before beginning the daunting process of removing more files I looked how much storage space I should have which was now at 22GB free. What happened to the other 18GB I had before the download began?

I've tried a restart, c-cleaner, and treeSize but I cant see anything out of the ordinary.

It wouldn't have allowed me to begin the first install unless there was 40GB free. So where did this space go to?

Comment: It’s extremely unlikely the Temporary Files is the literal Hyper-V Windows Feature.  What’s more likely it’s a virtual HDD file allocation, have you checked, for a folder of the name of the VM you attempted to create and/or to delete the VM within Hyper-V manager?

Comment: Yes just searched the C drive for the folder, no sign of it. Also the VM doesnt exist within the hyper V manager